# SML getting an unbound variable or constructor error when everything seems right

Tags: sml, ml

I'm trying to figure out mutual recursion. I have this code:

```
fun take(L)=
      if L=nil then nil
      else hd(L) :: skip(tl(L))
AND
fun skip(L)=
      if L=nil then nil
      else take(tl(L));
```

but it gives me these errors:

```
stdIn:54.14-54.18 Error: unbound variable or constructor: skip
stdIn:55.1-55.4 Error: unbound variable or constructor: AND
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your immediate error is because Standard ML is case-sensitive, and all of its reserved words are in lowercase; so you need to write `and` rather than `AND`.

Additionally, `fun` introduces an entire declaration, not an individual binding, meaning that you need to remove the extra `fun` after `and`.

Lastly, your functions currently require the list to have an equality type (such as `int list` or `string list`), which may not be a deal-breaker, but given what the functions actually do, there's really no reason they can't support non-equality types such as `real list`. To achieve that, you should *match* the parameter against the *pattern* `nil`, instead of testing whether the parameter *equals* `nil`. (More generally, you should use pattern-matching in more places; you have no reason to call `hd` and `tl`.)

Putting it together:

```
fun take nil = nil
  | take (h::t) = h :: skip t
and skip nil = nil
  | skip (h::t) = take t
```

Comment: Tried doing that, all I was just change 'AND' to 'and' and got these errors 

`stdIn:125.1-126.9 Error: syntax error: deleting  AND FUN ID 
stdIn:127.2-127.6 Error: syntax error: deleting  IF ID 
stdIn:127.11 Error: syntax error found at THEN`

Comment: @h2oBoost: Yes, sorry, I only addressed the error in the question. I've now expanded the answer to explain a few other issues with your code (and how to fix them).

Comment: @h2oBoost: The part about equality types: If you notice, your functions have type `''a list -> ''a list` while @ruakh's functions have type `'a list -> 'a list`. It is altogether unnecessary to require that input list elements have an equality type, but another point to make is this: When you do `xs = ys` to see if two things are equal, that provokes a deep traversal of the two structures `xs` and `ys`; naturally, this is not a problem here since you are comparing against `[]` and this deep traversal isn't so deep after all. But don't get used to compare things if you can do with less. :)